# Unmap <c-n> / <c-p> in completion menu to use as previous / next snippet placeholder with Coc

Tags: autocompletion, snippets, ins-completion, plugin-coc, popup-menu

My completion mappings scheme with [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/) is the following:

- `<c-@>` (ctrl-space): trigger the menu / use the selected item (or the first one)
- `<c-j>` and `<c-k>`: navigate the list (or also trigger the menu)
- `<c-n>` and `<c-p>`: jump between snippets placeholders

Which translates as:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-@> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr> <c-j> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr> <c-k> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : coc#refresh()
let g:coc_snippet_next = <c-n>
let g:coc_snippet_prev = <c-p>
```

This works pretty well (and I'm glad each key does only one thing and my "tab" and "enter", which are `<c-i>` and `<c-m>`, are not remapped).

Unfortunately, when the popup completion menu is shown, the default behavior (navigate the menu) takes over the global variable given by the plugin.

I tried the following (and more) to definitely shut the mapping when the menu is visible, with no success:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-n> pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>" : ""
inoremap <expr> <c-n> pumvisible() ? "\<nop>" : "\<nop>"
inoremap <expr> <c-n> "\<nop>"
inoremap <c-n> <nop>
```

Doing so, I noticed `<c-n>` and `<c-p>` seem to be affected only by the `pumvisible()` check for the regular pop menu, and not by the `coc` pop menu.

It's really driving me nuts since the above mappings, which use the same check, do work as intended.

Also, there's something in the help from `coc` which could possibly point the the right direction:

```
    inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm()
            \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"
```

It uses `coc`'s functions, which are not documented. I guess there's one to jump between placeholders, but I'm not able to find id.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Hey not a long time ago I was also looking to have the same setup as yours and ended up with this config. Although I ended up using `<c-j>` and `<c-k>` for navigating the completion list and also for snippet jumps.

```
let g:coc_snippet_next = ''
let g:coc_snippet_prev = ''
inoremap <expr> <c-j>
   \ pumvisible() ? "\<c-n>" :
   \ coc#jumpable() ? "\<c-r>=coc#rpc#request('snippetNext', [])<cr>" :
   \ "\<c-j>"
inoremap <expr> <c-k>
   \ pumvisible() ? "\<c-p>" :
   \ coc#jumpable() ? "\<c-r>=coc#rpc#request('snippetPrev', [])<cr>" :
   \ "\<c-k>"
```

Comment: Well, I ended up using `<c-b>` and `<c-f>` for snippet jumps to avoid confusion. Thanks for your solution though, I'll try that out.